# find the big oh for the function $f(n) =1+4+7+\cdots+(3n+1)$. Can someone explain why the answer is $n^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is a review question and the teachers gave us the answer as $n^2$. Can someone explain why it is $n^2$?

Thank you

Comment: We have
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2i+1=n^2.
$$
I believe you can modify this to solve your problem.

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples), and note that $\displaystyle\sum_0^n(3k+1)=3\sum_0^nk+\sum_0^n1=3\cdot S_n+(n+1)$.

Answer (score 4):

It is a sum of $n$ terms, each bounded by $4 n$, so bounded by $n \cdot 4 n = O(n^2)$.

(Yes, this is much less detailed than the other answers; but it also has the virtue that it doesn't require to get anywhere near the precise sum.)

Answer (score 3):

If $$g(n)=0+1+2+\cdots +n= \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ then $$f(n)=3g(n)+ (n+1) = \dfrac{(3n+2)(n+1)}{2}$$ which is $O(n^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
s_n=1+4+7+\cdots+(3n+1)=\frac{3n^2+5n+2}{2}={\mathcal O}(n^2),
$$
since
$$
\frac{s_n}{n^2}
$$
is bounded, and in particular,
$$
\frac{3}{2}\le \frac{s_n}{n^2}\le 5.
$$